# RethinkDB generate key-value pair from rows

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I have following query which returns the number of request for each status -

```
r.db.table("request").group("status").count()
```

result -

```
[
  {
    "group": "ACCEPTED",
    "reduction": 1
  },
  {
    "group": "DECLINED",
    "reduction": 1
  },
  {
    "group": "PENDING",
    "reduction": 1
  }
]
```

How can I convert this result to the following using rethinkdb query (javascript)?

```
{
  "ACCEPTED": 1,
  "DECLINED": 1,
  "PENDING": 1
}
```

Currently, I am achieving this by iterating the result in api side. But I want this transformation in rethinkdb, if its at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   r.db("test").table("request").group("status").count()
    .ungroup()
    .map(function(x){ return [x('group'), x('reduction')]; })        
    .coerceTo("object")
```

- When you want to continue working on your return object you need to
  call the `ungroup()` function first
- Then you need to use the map
  function to transform your result to:

  [ [ "ACCEPTED" , 1 ] , [ "DECLINED" , 1 ] , [ "PENDING" , 1 ] ]
- at last you simply transform this to a json-object with `coerceTo("object")`, which returns you the desired format:

  {
    "ACCEPTED": 1,
    "DECLINED": 1,
    "PENDING": 1
  }